# Відповідник до слова "копірайтер"

Tags: відповідник

Копірайтер - фахівець з написання текстів рекламного змісту. Цікавить, чи є в українській мові відповідник до цього слова.

На сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/kopiraiter) бачимо найпопулярніший відповідник "гаслотворець", однак погоджуся із наступним коментарем до цього варіанту:

> Гарний відповідник, але є одне "але" - "Гасло - Висловлена у стислій
>   формі ідея, політична вимога, завдання; заклик.", а копірайтери пишут
>   не тільки рекламні гасла, але й "...презентационные тексты. Таковыми
>   можно считать все тексты, которые прямым или косвенным образом
>   рекламируют или популяризируют товар, компанию, услугу, человека или
>   идею." Даруйте,що російською. Сьогодні популярні послуги копірайтерів,
>   що пишуть саме "довгі" тексти.

Маючи досвід роботи у цій сфері, можу зауважити, що копірайтери не завжди займаються лише короткими рекламними текстами, іноді вони пишуть і довгі статті (у яких все ж є реклама якогось товару, сервісу тощо). Трішки кращий варіант "писар", однак також можу погодитися із коментарями на тому ж Словотворі, що це слово не зовсім точно передає суть роботи "копірайтера". І хоч мені дуже сподобався варіант "текстовик", однак такого слова немає в СУМі. Отож: чи є в нашій мові якийсь відповідник, яким би можна було описати людину, яка пише рекламні тексти, але необов'язково короткі гасла? Чи можливо таке слово утворити об'єднавши два слова з української мови?

Також, якщо розглядаємо слово "копірайтер", то хотілося б знайти ще й відповідник до слова "[копірайтинг](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)" - професійна діяльність, написання рекламних і презентаційних текстів (реклама (пряма або прихована) товару, компанії, послуги тощо).

Answer (score 2):

В українській мові цілком нормативним є вживання слова ***"копірайтер"***, оскільки внесене в СУМ-20

> ***[КОПІРАЙТЕР](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=209661&page=1392)*** а, ч. Автор рекламних текстів, слоганів і т. ін. – *Нам потрібен копірайтер. Ти людина широкої ерудиції і прекрасно
>   підходиш для цього* (С. Пиркало); *Орієнтуючись на конкретного
>   споживача, реклама набуває оригінальності й динамічності, за допомогою
>   яких копірайтер змушує читача до розшифрування прихованого
>   повідомлення та привертає його увагу до товару* (з наук. літ.).

З цього ж словника

> ***[КОПІРАЙТИНГ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=209660&page=1392)*** у, ч. Написання рекламних текстів, слоганів і т. ін. на будь-яку тематику. *Історія копірайтингу віддзеркалює процес
>   розвитку рекламних текстів* (з наук.-попул. літ.); *Копірайтинг – це
>   мистецтво цікавого, яскравого та ефективного рекламування товарів та
>   послуг* (з навч. літ.).

На мою думку, краще використовувати саме ***копірайтер*** та ***копірайтинг*** не замінюючи іншими словами.